# CIFS share got full while running script, all processes got stuck with a D State.What to do?

Tags: mount, network-shares, samba

The title pretty much says it all.

I had a little script in charge of compressing and copying files to a MS Shared folder.

Apparently, one day last week other processes also had to copy files to the same server and the whole thing got hung up because it ran out of space.

Trying to do any command in the mounted share folder, in this case /mnt/samba, results in the terminal hanging forever. Even trying `kill -9 pid` does nothing.

I'm guessing some main process is there clogging the whole thing.

I tried a `sudo umount -l`, and, while the mounted share appears unmounted, the processes are still there, running, and because of that I cannot mount it again properly (I can get into the share via the Connect to server... dialog in the Gnome desktop, but I need to mount it via `mount`) .

I can see the commands of the script trying to run indefinitely, but, like I say before, I cannot kill them, not even from the root user. I've already restart the `smb` service, but nothing either.

Is there a way to force timeout on the cifs share o some way to completely kill all the related running processes so I can mount again the share? (sadly, reboot is not an option at this moment xD).

I can let live those D processes there, but I need to be able to mount again the share. Any ideas?